# QGIS Create a new point snapped at a specific distance on a line from the previous point

Tags: qgis, point, distance, snapping

I am running QGIS 3.10.6 A Coruna
I have a train line vector that has geometry of type Line (MultiLineStringZ). CRS is EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid.
I need to create points at specific (but variable) distances along the line.
At present, I review other layers (e.g land topography and land use) surrounding the line and decide which distance based on 1 of 6 options. I then use the measurement tool to step down the line (snapping to the line as I go) and place a point at the approximate required distance down the line. Then repeat...
This is tedious and accuracy is variable.

Is there a way of entering a distance in some field of a plugin that snaps the next point to the distance entered?

Comment: You could buffer by distance X and the snap the new point to the intersection of buffer & line - still tedious, but accurate. `Points along lines` or `interpolate point` probably wont suit your case.

Comment: To be able to help you, it would be easier what you mean by "points at specific (but variable) distances" " based on 1 of 6 options" from "other layers". Be more specific - best add a few screenshots that show what you want to do and even better also provide sample data for testing. Otherwise, it's almost impossible to image what you need.

Comment: Feedback to Erik: Thanks for the answer I thought about that but unfortunately the train line has many curves and I need the points to be located based on specific line lengths. Your approach would work very well for a straight line but not with my dataset.

Comment: Feedback to Babel: "other layers": one is a raster that has clutter data. Clutter data in my case is land use with heights (e.g. suburban houses, urban tall buildings, trees, open land.. etc). The other is a vector layer which identifies if the train line is in a "cutting". A cutting is an area of track with very steep embankments either side. "points at specific...distances... 1 of 6..." means I have cell tower ranges that can propagate to certain distances on the track based on clutter and cuttings. I look at the layers on the map and decide which one to use for my next point.